# Getting CREATE FUNCTION must be the only statement in the batch - SQLServer

Tags: sql, sql-server

In the following query, I get 'must be the only statement in the batch' error

```
CREATE FUNCTION IsManager
(@EnteredEmployeeID DECIMAL(11,0))
RETURNS FLOAT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Ret DECIMAL;
    SELECT @Ret = ManagerID 
    FROM Manager
    WHERE ManagerID = EnteredEmployeeID;

    IF(@Ret>0)  
        RETURN 0.03
    ELSE
        RETURN 0.02
END
```

A few suggestions was to remove the @ symbol of the input variable  and that results in another error as it is expecting a variable.

Please let me know what's wrong with this query and Thank you in advance

Comment: sqlserver or mysql ?

Comment: @VBoka SQL Server

Comment: @VBoka I went and verified and tried other methods before asking this question

Comment: Ohh I apologize for that.. but I haven't gotten an answer yet or at least it is still not working

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3c1adec154d27cacd5b60a2624dab198)

```
CREATE FUNCTION IsManager(@EnteredEmployeeID DECIMAL(11,0))
RETURNS FLOAT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Ret DECIMAL, @result FLOAT;
    SELECT @Ret = ManagerID 
    FROM Manager
    WHERE ManagerID = @EnteredEmployeeID;

    IF(@Ret>0)  
        set @result = 0.03
    ELSE
        set @result = 0.02

    return @result
END
```

I have founded few things:

1. You are selecting a data from a table and in your where clause you need to use a variable that you have forwarded to the function when you call her. So instead of this:

   ```
   WHERE ManagerID = EnteredEmployeeID;
   ```

   this:

   ```
   WHERE ManagerID = @EnteredEmployeeID;
   ```
2. You have to set the value to some variable and then return it with return statement at the end...So instead of this:

   ```
   IF(@Ret>0)  
      RETURN 0.03
   ELSE
      RETURN 0.02
   ```

   this:

   ```
   IF(@Ret>0)  
      set @result = 0.03
   ELSE
      set @result = 0.02

   return @result
   ```

I have done some more research and this is why I asked you "how do you run this statement ? Do you only trying to run this one create function statement ?". Please do confirm that this is not your case:

> As the error message suggests, the CREATE FUNCTION statement must be
>   the first statement in a query batch. There should be no other
>   statements before the CREATION FUNCTION statement that would make it
>   not the first statement in a query batch.

If it is then just ad keyword GO between the statements.

Here is a nice explanation:

http://www.sql-server-helper.com/error-messages/msg-111-create-function.aspx

Comment: Still the same error:: Create function must be the only statement in the batch

Comment: Hi @PatrickAdjei how do you run this statement ? Do you only trying to run this one create function statement ?

Comment: Yes, I will run the one function statement. But before I even get to run it, I can the error...

Comment: Hi @PatrickAdjei I have updated my answer again. Hope this will be the one for you...

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
CREATE TABLE Manager (ManagerID int);

CREATE FUNCTION IsManager(EnteredEmployeeID DECIMAL)
RETURNS FLOAT
BEGIN
  DECLARE Ret DECIMAL;
    SELECT Ret = ManagerID 
    FROM Manager
    WHERE ManagerID = EnteredEmployeeID;

    IF(Ret>0)  
        RETURN 0.03
    ELSE
        RETURN 0.02
END
```

Sample SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b8a695